# create a shortcode for cpt and custom taxonomy to list post titles

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, wordpress-shortcode, taxonomy-terms

**LATEST UPDATE:** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76409524/14322884)! is the solution in my case.

im trying to creating a shortcode for cpt and custom taxonomy to list post titles

im using this codes to list the post titles:

```
function kat_post_list_func($atts)
{
    $category_id = $atts['cat'];
    $args = array('category' => $category_id, 'post_type' => 'post');
    $cat_posts = get_posts($args);
 
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $posts_per_page = 2;
    $offset = ($paged - 1) * $posts_per_page;
    $total_pages = ceil(count($cat_posts) / $posts_per_page);
 
    $args['numberposts'] = $posts_per_page;
    $args['offset'] = $offset;
    $cat_posts = get_posts($args);
 
    $tablo = "<table>";
    $tablo .= "<tr>";
    $tablo .= "<th>Başlık</th>";
    $tablo .= "<th>Yazar</th>";
    $tablo .= "</tr>";
 
    foreach ($cat_posts as $post) {
        $author_name = get_the_author_meta('display_name', $post->post_author);
        $tablo .= "<tr>";
        $tablo .= "<td><a href='" . get_permalink($post->ID) . "'>" . $post->post_title . "</a></td>";
        $tablo .= "<td>" . $author_name . "</td>";
        $tablo .= "</tr>";
    }
 
    $tablo .= "</table>";
 
    $pagination = paginate_links(array(
        'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
        'format' => '/page/%#%',
        'current' => $paged,
        'total' => $total_pages,
        'prev_text' => __('« Önceki'),
        'next_text' => __('Sonraki »'),
    ));
 
    $output = '<div class="pagination">' . $pagination . '</div>';
 
    return $tablo . $output;
}
 
add_shortcode('kat_post_list', 'kat_post_list_func');
```

im using the shortcode likes this: `[kat_post_list cat=3]`

but now i need something different. i have a cpt called demo_listing and a custom taxonomy under that cpt called demo_8...

i want to list post titles for this cpt also but i can't figure out how: this is what i tried so far:

```
function kat_post_list_func($atts)
{
 
    $category_id = $atts['cat'];
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'demo_listing',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'demo_8',
                'field' => 'term_id',
                'terms' => $category_id
            )
        )
    );
    $cat_posts = get_posts($args);
```

can someone help me with that and tell me where i am wrong please?

**Update:** okay so this is what i can't figure out:

in the first codes this fecth the categories of the post post-type -> `$category_id = $atts['cat'];` but how can i get the terms for demo_8. demo_8 works like categories for posts.

**UPDATE 2:**

Now i changed my args:
but that codes print every post under the demo_listing cpt. i still can't let the my taxonomy involved. but i think im getting closer lol

```
$terms = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'demo_8',
    'fields'   => 'id=>slug',
) );
    
$args = array( 
    'post_type'      => 'demo_listing',
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'tax_query'      => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'demo_8',
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => array_keys( $terms ),
        ),
    ),
);
    $cat_posts = get_posts($args);
```

Comment: I would recommend if you want to use same shortcode to pass post_type and taxonomy as attributes too so you can use same shortcode for multiple post types.

Comment: i can add my cpt to args here: $args = array('category' => $category_id, 'post_type' => 'post'); but how can i add custom taxonomy?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would write the shortcode function (untested):

```php
function kat_post_list_func( $atts ) {
    $category_id = $atts['cat'];

    if ( empty( $category_id ) ) {
        trigger_error( 'No category provided.', E_USER_NOTICE );
        return;
    }

    $args = array( 
        'post_type'      => 'demo_listing',
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'no_found_rows'  => true,
        'tax_query'      => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'demo_8',
                'field'    => 'term_id',
                'terms'    => $category_id,
            ),
        ),
    );

    $cat_posts = new WP_Query( $args );
    
    if ( empty( $cat_posts->posts ) ) {
        echo 'No posts found.';
        return;
    }

    ...
}
```

If you're not getting results from this, try dumping `$cat_posts->query_vars` to check if there's any manipulation of the query parameters occurring.

```php
$cat_posts = new WP_Query( $args );
var_dump( $cat_posts->query_vars );
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Here is how i did it:

```
// Extract shortcode attributes
    $atts = shortcode_atts(array(
        'post_type' => 'demo_listing',
        'taxonomy' => 'demo_14',
        'term_id' => '',
    ), $atts, 'cpt_category_posts');

    // Query posts with the specified post type and taxonomy
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => $atts['post_type'],
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => $atts['taxonomy'],
                'field' => 'term_id',
                'terms' => $atts['term_id'],
            ),
        ),
        'posts_per_page' => 3, // Set to 3 to display 3 titles per page
        'paged' => get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1, // Get the current page number
    );
    $query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: I already tried to explain with the comment lines. i'm also new and the whole topic shows how i tried to figure it out. im not sure how i can explain more actually.

Answer (score -2):

```
function kat_post_list_func($atts) {
    $category_id = $atts['cat'];
    
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'demo_listing',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'demo_8',
                'field' => 'term_id',
                'terms' => $category_id
            )
        )
    );
    
    $cat_posts = get_posts($args);
 
    $tablo = "<table>";
    $tablo .= "<tr>";
    $tablo .= "<th>Başlık</th>";
    $tablo .= "<th>Yazar</th>";
    $tablo .= "</tr>";
 
    foreach ($cat_posts as $post) {
        $author_name = get_the_author_meta('display_name', $post->post_author);
        $tablo .= "<tr>";
        $tablo .= "<td><a href='" . get_permalink($post->ID) . "'>" . $post->post_title . "</a></td>";
        $tablo .= "<td>" . $author_name . "</td>";
        $tablo .= "</tr>";
    }
 
    $tablo .= "</table>";
 
    return $tablo;
}
 
add_shortcode('kat_post_list', 'kat_post_list_func');
```

Comment: this is the exact code i used. i can't figure out how $category_id = $atts['cat']; and 'terms' => $category_id works exactly. how can i change those to use with demo_8 taxonomy.

Comment: $category_id = $atts['cat']; retrieves the value of the attribute cat from the $atts array. This means that when you use the shortcode, you would pass a value for the cat attribute like this: [kat_post_list cat="category_id_value"].

Comment: got it. so it works for categories for post. but why not it works for custom taxonomy in a cpt? this is what i can't understand :(